# Optional arguments strings and data frame to a python function

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a function to perform multiple tasks. And I need to pass optional strings/variables and optional data frame with other values.
For example, this is my function.

```
def main(df,option=None,type=None, *args)
    if type == "cars":
       #multiple functions..
       df      = function1(df)
       results = function2(df)
       if option =="ex":
          results = function4(results)
       elif option =="CDS":
           result  = function5(results)
    elif type == "buses":
         df2 = pd_read_csv("data2",sep="\t",header=0) # This is the optional data frame I wannna pass
         def func3(df2,results,df):
             result["col3"] =pd.merge(df2,df, on="col1")
             return result
         if option =="ex":
            results = function4(results)
         elif option =="CDS":
            result  = function5(results)
     return(result)
```

I have two optional variables passed to my function `main` already `option` and `type`. Now I need to pass one more optional variable that is `df2`. But I do not know how can do it. The above example is a template from my main function. Here, I wanna add `df2` to the `main()` and use it in first `elif` loop for `buses`.

Any suggestions or help is much appreciated

Comment: `def main(df,option=None,type=None,df2=None, *args)`?

Comment: But how to call it later? I mean as a data frame. This is not a string and I want to call it in the `elif loop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need.

```
def main(df,option=None,type=None,df2=None, *args):
    if df2 is not None:
        #Process df2 ....
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use *args argument in main function to pass the optional parameters such as df2, as:

```
def main(df,option=None,type=None, *args):
    df2=args[0]    # here you will get the df2

# call main function as
main(df,option,type,df2)
```

**OR**

You can also use **kwargs** to pass keyword optional arguments as,

```
def main(df,option=None,type=None, **kwargs):
    df2=kwargs['df2']   # here you will get the df2

# call main function as
main(df,option,type,df2=df2)
```

Hope this helps!